# IOS: difference NSDate

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate

I have two nsdate, this moment date and a nsdate that I know;
I want to to the difference and I want as result seconds...

for actually NSDate it's not a problem but if I want NSDate for 13/09/2012 at 12:30?

can yuo help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSDateFormatter is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the string to a NSDate object...